# Execute jQuery queue random number of times

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue

I am using the jQuery `queue()` function to animate a set of images one after another. What I want is the queue to occur a random number of times each time it is executed. Here is the JS that sets the queue:

```
//rotate colors function
function rotateColors() {
    for (var i=0; i<7; i++) {
        isAnimating = true;
        color.delay(50).eq(i).fadeIn(100);
        color.delay(100).eq(i).fadeOut(100);
    }   
}
//rotate colors on button click
button.bind('click', function() {
    color.queue(function(n) {
        rotateColors();
        n();
    });
});
```

How can I make is so each time this queue is activated it will execute a random number of times?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.random()` to generate a random number.

```
function rotateColors() {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1; // generate random number between 1 and 10
    for (var i = 0; i < rnd; i++) {
        isAnimating = true;
        color.delay(50).eq(i).fadeIn(100);
        color.delay(100).eq(i).fadeOut(100);
    }   
}
//rotate colors on button click
button.bind('click', function() {
    color.clearQueue().queue(function(n) {
        rotateColors();
        n();
    });
});
```

Note I added `clearQueue()` to the `click` handler to prevent masses of actions building up on the queue on successive clicks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This seems like it would work, however now it's bringing in images randomly instead of executing them in order...

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything

Comment: I fixed this by setting max-min values in the `Math.random()` function. Because I have 7 images that must execute everytime, the min had to be set to 7. I want the queue to execute a maximum of 4 times, so my max number is 28 (7*4). Giving me this as my final random function: `var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (28 - 7) + 1) + 7;` -- but now, there is a delay between the time the queue ends and executes again. How can I remove that delay?